# does MTK share their AOSP source code? How can I get it?

Tags: android, android-source

Does MTK share their AOSP or kernel code? like Qualcomm's Code Aurora [https://source.codeaurora.org/] or google's Android OpenGrok [http://androidxref.com/] ?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, their devices are not open source.
You can get their kernel official source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/mediatek/), leaked AOSP [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2650513), and re-build from scratch project [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2274332).

Comment: Can you build a rom from the official source in your first link?